# Can't find IIS on Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: iis, windows-7

I just bought a brand new Lenovo (idealpad) laptop with Windows 7 Home Basic. There's no operating system DVD along with the stock, but the laptop does have OS recovery software, if you ever want to burn them on a DVD. I guess most hardware is being sold that way today.

Anyway, I want to use IIS. I followed [these steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx) to install it. I went to **Control Panel** -> **Programs** -> **Turn Windows features on or off**. I selected **Internet Information Services** from the list and let it install it. I think it must've gotten installed.

But now, I can't find it. I tried [these steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472%28WS.10%29.aspx) to locate **inetmgr** but neither can I find the MMC Snap-in UI. Where do I find IIS? I have even rebooted the machine and checked but no luck.

**Update on 23rd March 2011**

Guys, I installed IIS Express and have checked a lot pages on the Web but I cannot see the IIS snap-in (inetmgr) on my Windows 7 Home Basic box. Please help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: @Gabe: Please read my question. It is relevant. I have purchased Windows 7 Home Basic and am entitled to IIS out of the box. I am sure that it is installed properly. But I cannot locate the Internet Services Manager.

Comment: Are you saying that the Web Platform Installer won't do what you want? It installs IIS, SQL Server, VS, etc.

Comment: I know that it does. But my question was about a frustrating experience I was having about finding IIS Manager. Even if I installed IIS AGAIN using the Web PI installer, as pointed out below in one of my comments to another user, it would not have shown up on my OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb).

I have fallen in love with it and I'm sure you will to.

Comment: Apparently, like another user pointed out (whose post has been deleted), inetmgr isn't available on Windows 7 Home Basic. I'll need to either upgrade the OS and pay more or, like you said, I could install IIS Express. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Open the Command Prompt and type

Iisreset /noforce

If this errors out IIS wasnt installed correctly or was not installed at all.

Comment: You still can install it but you wont have all the options please see this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx I would suggest using IIS Express if you are using Basic but other wise you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could find it by just pressing start and type it in the search bar.
May be a lame idea you already tried, but it costed me half an hour before i figured it out.