# Cannot find inetmgr on Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-express

I have been trying for over a month now.

[Can't find IIS on Windows 7 Home Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933895/cant-find-iis-on-windows-7-home-basic)

I have looked around and read a lot of web pages and tried every suggestion possible but haven't been able to find the IIS snap in (inetmgr) on my Windows 7 Home Basic installation.

I first checked IIS in the 'Turn Windows features on or off' and when that didn't work, I got and installed IIS Express and checked if the InetMgr option was turned on in the 'Turn Windows features on or off.' But nothing has worked.

Please help.

I need to do some ASP.NET development. Please also suggest an web server that will work on Windows 7 Home Basic and will support ASP.NET and PHP. Cassini?

Comment: IIS Express does not use the IIS 7.5 management console. Visual Web Developer 2010 Express with Service Pack 1 allows you to use IIS Express to host your website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebMatrix (which uses IIS Express Web Server). http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

IIS Express runs on Windows 7 home basic and also supports both asp.net and php

Comment: Indeed IIS, including IIS Manager are not available in Windows Home Basic SKUs, however as mentioned above, IIS Express and WebMatrix are the best option.